# How can I bridge wpa_supplicant with java?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna

Has anyone found a solution to interact with wpa_supplicant in a java application (JNA,JNI)?

In the same style that Android has that ability, I would like to manage wpa_supplicant within my custom embeeded application, but after days off looking through the web, the only java interface to wpa_supplicant I have found is in Android.

Can someone help me?

(No, I don't want to interact with wpa_cli via `Runtime.exec()`).

Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: My mom said "I" is always capital on English, I think it is not a big problem if give I further what she said.

Comment: Sorry for that, I wrote this in a smartphone, on a hurry. I'm sorry if I ofended you.

Comment: No problem, I fixed your question. Good luck here in the future!